how to do it in openlayer like leaflet draw style editor

I have researched and searched many times and can't find examples of style editors on openlayers. Available only on leaflets. Please share your experience, how should I write it?
It's fine if you include example code.

I don't know if this addresses your problem.
But it is very easy to implement a panel with custom buttons. To do this you must link your panel to the map controls. Then play with the events that interest you, like drawevents.
I do it in a React project for example, where I myself made my panel allowing me to draw a line, a rectangle, a point or just to measure a distance.
map.addControl(new Control({ element: refDrawPanel.current }))

<div ref={refDrawPanel} style={{ position: "absolute", right: 8, top: 8 }}>
<Button .... />
</div>

